# How to solve MapperParsingException: object mapping for [test] tried to parse as object, but got EOF

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasicSearch i created one index "test" and mappings like below

```
{
  "index": {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "test"
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.number_of_shards": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "date_detection": false
    },
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "dateModified": {
          "dynamic": "true",
          "properties": {
            "date": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "time": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index is created successfully.
I given date like

```
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"test"}}
{"dateModified":{"date":"25/05/2015","time":"17:54 IST"}}
```

Record inserted succesfully.If i give data like below it giving error

```
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"test"}}
    {"dateModified":"25/05/2015"}

org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping for [test] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:498)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:541)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:490)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:511)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Then how to solve this problem,I read some blog and posts related to this issue but they don't given solution to this problem.

Answer (score 32):

To solve this issue, you need to index the same type of value in the field `dateModified`. It sounds like you indexed an inner element in one document and the string value in the next document.

The mapping for `dateModified` field is kind of a `inner object` which has 2 fields, `date` & `time`. The mapping also `dynamic` which has created while you index the first document.

**1st Document**

```
{
    "dateModified": {
        "date": "25/05/2015",
        "time": "17:54 IST"
    }
}
```

**2nd Document**

```
{
    "dateModified": "25/05/2015"
}
```

It clearly says that you are trying to index a document with different type of values for a particular field. which is not supported by elastic search. Each and every field should have a unique data type and the values also should be same as defined in the mapping.

This causes the problem. Don't try to index different type of values in a single field in different documents.

Comment: Yes, looks like you can't store different value types in a single field. Same thing mentioned here: http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/04/elasticsearch-object-mapping-eof-400.html

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, first I have indexed a document with one filed of type List and it was working, then I changed the value from simple String to an Object(user defined model, eg: Employee, which converted to Json String), then I was getting the above issue.

Updated the previous documents and mappings, then it started working