# Error when trying to rename a nested object name in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-nested

I'm trying to rename data that is in this shape:

[image]

using this:

```
POST r_xair_signals-2020-06/_update/2020-06-15T22:23:00Z_-1344027716
{
  "doc" : {
        "Customer ImpactedNested" : "CustomerImpactedNested"
    }
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "object mapping for [Customer ImpactedNested] tried to parse field [Customer ImpactedNested] as object, but found a concrete value"
```

I've confirmed the type of Customer ImpactedNested is nested.  I see info online about people getting this error, but not when trying to rename, and don't see any solutions.  I saw one article that indicated it occurred when the new name conflicted with an existing name.  So, tried renaming to CustomerImpactedNested11111 as a test (sure to be unique), but same result.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: I found a way around this problem, and I haven't been able to test your answer yet.  Plan to by the end of the week, though.  And thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems actually.

1. Your query is not renaming the field.
2. Renaming the nested field

What is happening actually in the following line from the question:

```
POST r_xair_signals-2020-06/_update/2020-06-15T22:23:00Z_-1344027716
{
  "doc" : {
        "Customer ImpactedNested" : "CustomerImpactedNested"
    }
}
```

It updates **column value** of `column=Customer ImpactedNested` to `CustomerImpactedNested` document whose id is `2020-06-15T22:23:00Z_-1344027716`.

And `Customer ImpactedNested` is a nested object and you are trying to set a `string` value to the nested object field. Hence you are getting the error. [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454108/how-to-solve-mapperparsingexception-object-mapping-for-test-tried-to-parse-as)

Coming to your original problem, you need to do this via `reindex`. [Refer this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-rename-nested-fields-using-reindex/144956/2), [this also](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-change-name)

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "r_xair_signals-2020-06"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "<some_new_index_name>"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": """ctx._source['CustomerImpactedNested'] = ctx._source.remove("Customer ImpactedNested")"""
  }
}
```

Please try the above and let me know for errors as I didn't try the above query.

Comment: The above worked after I changed the destination index to a different index.  When I tried it as it was, an error about not being able to reindex into the index being read from.  There is an explanation of why from an elastic engineer: "We chose not to let reindex index back to the same index because for the most part it isn't the right thing to do. . . ." It is a comment from nik9000 on Feb 9, 2017 here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23033.  There is more in the comment than I'm including here.